# Dynamic SUM function & filtering

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Power Query table that updates on a regular basis. The table has columns named "Volume Third Party_*some number*". After the update, the number of the column with this name *may increase or decrease*. At the end of the table, there is a calculated column that has the formula to subtract from the last column with the name sum of the columns with the name written above.

In the power query editor, I couldn't find any formula which would help me to get the last column with the name, so instead, I'm trying to create a dynamic SUM function/sub procedure that would get the last column with the name "Volume Third Party_*some number*".

I have attached a screenshot [image: screen]

and from it, you can see there is a column "Volume Third Party_47" and column "Volume Third Party_48". After the update "Volume Third Party_48" was added but the SUM function is referring to the values from the column "Volume Third Party_47". So instead I need a function/sub procedure in VBA which would change the reference to the last column in the formula, in this case to the column "Volume Third Party_48" and also put a filter to a new reference column (it should remove 0 & blank values), while deleting it from another one.

Any ideas on how to make this VBA code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be made possible using some change in excel formula.

If the name of you table is `Table1` and the first column header of your table is `firstColumn`, then you need to replace `[@[Volume_Third_Party_47]]` in your formula with

```
OFFSET([@[firstColumn],,COUNTA(Table1[#Headers])-2)
```

But you entire formula should be something like this:

```
=IFERROR(
   OFFSET([@Column1];;COUNTA(SAPCrosstab_UA[#Headers])-3)-
   SUM(
      OFFSET([@[Volume Third Party]];;;;
                (COUNTA(SAPCrosstab_UA[#Headers])-1) - 
                 MATCH("Volume Third Party",SAPCrosstab_UA[#Headers],0)
            )
      );
"")
```

Comment: I might have some syntax errors here since I don't have the exact name of your table and columns. Cross check the formula and make changes accordingly

Comment: Thank you very much!